# How to do ajax synchronous call from Chrome's window.onunload?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, synchronous, onunload

I'm trying to do a jquery .ajax synchronous call on window.onunload. FF and IE works but not on Chrome. I had done some testing and Chrome seems to terminate the window and not wait for the response.

Here is my code:

```
window.onunload = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/someurl",
        async: false,
        data: ({ somedata: "test" }),
        success: function(){ return true; },
        error: function(){ alert('got some error'); }
    });
}
```

Note that I'm using window.onbeforeunload to display a warning message, then trigger the window.unload when the user leaves the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use `onbeforeunload` instead of `onunload`, and that should do the trick. You need to wrap both of your events into that one action. `onunload` won't fire in Chrome.